# Python Skipping a Parameter in a Function

Tags: python

Beginner Here and I just want to know how to skip a parameter in python for example

```
def function(a, b):
    pass

function(5)
```

I want to only assign 5 to b. How can I do it?

Comment: And what do you expect the value of `a` to be in that case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def function(a=None, b=None):
    pass

function(b=5)
```

This makes the values that don't get assigned `None` (in this case `a` is gonna be `None`).

If you don't add `=None` to the two parameters, it will throw an error because I didn't assign anything to `a`.

If in the last line you don't say `b=5` and instead say just `5`, it will think that is for the `a` parameter since the `a` parameter is before the `b` parameter in the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, You can set a default value to `a` in that case.

```
def function(b,a=None):
pass

function(5)
```

Please note that the default parameters are supposed to follow the non-defualt ones.